# Graphics3D does not properly render color

Tags: plotting, graphics

The objective is simple draw a triangle in the 3D space and the plane determined by it. I use the following commands,

```
threePoints = {{1, 0.7, 0}, {0, 1, 0.2}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}};
Graphics3D[{InfinitePlane[threePoints], Blue, Polygon[threePoints]}, 
 Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 2}}, 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

The outcome is the following, with the triangle partially painted blue. Anyone can help with this? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Well, the polygons are directly overlapping, that's what you get, try changing it to `Polygon[threePoints + {0.01, 0.01, 0.01}]`

Comment: @Feyre Thank you! This works!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Feyre says, the problem is that the two shapes are coincident.  Offsetting them slightly will make the triangle completely visible (or invisible).  An alternative is to modify the `Opacity` (plane partially transparent and triangle opaque).  The result is not perfect at all angles, but may be good enough.

```
threePoints = {{1, 0.7, 0}, {0, 1, 0.2}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}};
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], InfinitePlane[threePoints], Opacity[1], 
  Blue, Polygon[threePoints]}, Axes -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 2}}, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image]